# how to render new elements at the end of current screen - REACT NATIVE

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm working on a news app, and this is the news details screens, it renders all the news details but i want to render the next news below this one when the end is reached. I can manage to get the new news details by using isCloseToBottom method and i can render the new news but the old one get replaced, but i don't want the old news to disappear.  Is there any workaround for this?

```
  class NewsDetails extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            visible: false,
            loaded: false,
            article: {},
            request_control:1
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
        console.log(params.id);
        axios
            .get(`${URL_NEWS_DETAILS}/${params.id}`)
            .then(response =>
                this.setState({
                    article: response.data,
                    loaded: true,
                })
            )
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }


    _onRefresh=()=>{
        this.setState({refreshing: true})
        axios.get(`${URL_NEWS_DETAILS}/210971`) //test with constant id
            .then(response =>
                this.setState({
                    article: response.data,
                    loaded: true,
                })
            )
            .catch(error => console.log(error));

        this.setState({refreshing: false});

    };


    renderNext=()=>{

        if(this.state.request_control===1) {
            this.setState({request_control: 0});
            axios.get(`${URL_NEWS_DETAILS}/210971`) //test with constant id
                .then(response => {
                        this.setState({
                            request_control:1,
                            article: response.data,
                            loaded: true
                        })

                    },
                )
                .catch(error => {
                    this.setState({ loaded: true})
                    console.log(error)
                })
        }

    };



    render() {
        if (this.state.loaded) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                                onScroll={({nativeEvent}) => {
                                    if (isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)) {
                                        this.renderNext()
                                    }
                                }}
                                scrollEventThrottle={400}
                                refreshControl={
                                    <RefreshControl
                                        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                                        onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
                                    />
                                }>
                        <Text style={styles.title}>
                            {this.state.article.title.rendered.replace("&#8211;", "-")}
                        </Text>

                        <View
                            style={{ marginTop: 10, marginBottom: 10, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <Image
                                style={{ width: 18, height: 18 }}
                                source={require('../../img/icon.png')}
                            />
                            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Open Sans Bold', fontSize: 14 }}>
                                {' '}
                                {this.state.article.author}
                            </Text>
                            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Open Sans Regular', fontSize: 13 }}>
                                {' '}
                                në{' '}
                            </Text>
                            {this.state.article.categories.map(category => {
                                return (
                                    <Text
                                        style={{
                                            fontFamily: 'Open Sans Regular',
                                            fontSize: 13,
                                            color: '#F33A22',
                                        }}>
                                        {category.name},{' '}
                                    </Text>
                                );
                            })}
                        </View>

                        <Lightbox underlayColor="white">
                            <Image
                                style={styles.image}
                                source={{ uri: this.state.article.featured_image_url }}
                            />
                        </Lightbox>

                        <HTMLView
                            value={'<div>' + this.state.article.content.raw + '</div>'}
                            renderNode={Platform.OS === 'android' ? this.renderNode : null}
                            stylesheet={htmlStyles}
                        />


                        {/*HERE I NEED TO RENDER A NEW NEWS BELOW THE MAIN ONE, */}
                        {/*TO CREATE AN EFFECT LIKE USED IN WEB THAT DISPLAYS NEWS AFTER NEWS*/}


                    </ScrollView>
                </View>
            );
        } else return <Spinner />;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your state `article` is replaced by the new one when you call `renderNext`, so the old one get replaced. To fix that, just change like

```js
    renderNext=()=>{

        if(this.state.request_control===1) {
            this.setState({request_control: 0});
            axios.get(`${URL_NEWS_DETAILS}/210971`) //test with constant id
                .then(response => {
                        this.setState({
                            request_control:1,
                            article: [...this.state.article, ...response.data],
                            loaded: true
                        })

                    },
                )
                .catch(error => {
                    this.setState({ loaded: true})
                    console.log(error)
                })
        }

    };
```

Comment: You would also need to change the render function to support multiple news articles. You should use the FlatList component instead of ScrollView, which actually has an onEndReached function built in as well.

Comment: @tuấn-trần-duy i get an undefined is not an object ( this.state.article.title.rendered)

Comment: Just append your new data from request to old state `article`. May be you could try to console.log your new state, and fix structure